# Error: Missing "key" prop for element in array react/jsx-key

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When I try to build my `next.js` app, I'm receiving the following error:
`Error: Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key` in every component:
[image]

I only use the `map` function once in my project and did put the `key` prop:
[image]

And I cannot understand why I'm getting that error, not that at I also got the following error at the end:
[image]

Comment: the error come from 2 different files, so maybe you should share the content of those files. Also screenshots are not recommended here

Comment: @Crocsx i'm having this problem in every component even though i don't have a ```map``` function except in 1 component where I did give a ```key``` property

Comment: @Daniel_Kamel, Can you add all three component code and also where you have imported the component.

Answer (score -1):

Pass **key={index}** prop to **RightPackage** instead of sending to **div**

Comment: unfortunately,did not work!

Comment: passing `index` can cause another separate error, so likely not correct. @Daniel_Kamel was it the same error after trying this or a new one?

Answer (score -1):

It seems, you need to pass key props in the RightPackage component.

```
{rightPackages.map((item, index) => (
  <div key={`right-package${index`}>
    <RightPackage key={index.toString()} />
</div>

) )}
```

or you can pass if item is having any unique id.

Comment: @Daniel, let us know this solution work or not .

Comment: no unfortunatly it did not work

Comment: if the problem was from that the error would have ended with ```in iterator react/jsx-key ``` not with ```in map react/jsx-key```

Comment: this code is incorrectly written (there should be another curry bracket after `index`) but also using 'index' is another eslint rule violation.

Answer (score -4):

It turned out that the solution was to disable eslint, This can be done by going to `next.config.js` file and adding the following:

```
eslint: {
        ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
    },
```

like this:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    eslint: {
        ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
    },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Comment: Your own answer is wrong, and adding `ignoreDuringBuilds: true` is risky unless you are absolutely sure all your lint rules are correct. Please look at other answers about adding key prop to the first element of your `.map`

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial what dou you mean I'm wrong?? I fixed the problem when I added it!

Comment: You are only **hiding** the error, you are not **fixing** the error. In react, if you do not provide a key prop to a array being rendered, React will not know what it is rendering. When you provide a key prop, React can "remember" the element, and decide whether to re-render or not.

Comment: You need to provide the key prop to all the components that are being sounded by eslint.

Comment: Since I am in a position where I am "absolutely sure all my lint rules are correct", this answer was helpful to me and I'm upvoting it.